# Vagrant CentOS guest's IP is not resolved in Arch Linux host

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtualbox

I had a `vagrantfile` working ([here](https://github.com/jaguililla/hexagon/blob/master/vagrantfile)).

But after updating my Linux version (4.4 to 4.8). It stopped resolving the guest address (192.168.0.210). I do not know if this could be the cause.

I installed VirtualBox and Kernel modules for Linux 4.8.

These are the versions I'm using:

- Manjaro Linux (Arch Linux)
- Kernel 4.4 or 4.8 (I tried with both)
- Vagrant 1.9.1
- VirtualBox 5.1.10 r112026

When I ping the guest, this is what I get:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.210
PING 192.168.0.210 (192.168.0.210) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
```

However, if I ping the network address directly, it suceed:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
```

This is the vbox network:

```
vboxnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 68  bytes 8598 (8.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

On the guest. These are the network interfaces:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:d8:71:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 85612sec preferred_lft 85612sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fed8:7180/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:20:77:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe20:770b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The firewall was disabled on host and guest while I was testing it.

Any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: how many network interfaces do you have in the guest - does `sudo ifconfig` resolves the IP ? did you check if any firewall have been reinitialiezed after the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is a bug with Vagrant 1.9.1 (reverting to 1.9.0 works ok).

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8142